# Figuring out proper preg_match regex matching

Tags: php, regex

I am curling a page with php and then I am looking to find a section within that page. That section opens and closes with the html5 `<section>` tag like this:

```
<section id="postingbody">
   blah blah blah content
</section>
```

I am not sure how to get my matching working properly. Just to fill in the matching portion here:

```
preg_match("/ id=\"postingbody\"\">???????<\/section>/i", $compiled_results, $matches2);
```

### Edit

So here is an example section of the content

```
<section id="postingbody">
    Looking to find a side job ( working your own hours ) or career in the new media field & internet marketing? Web design, graphic design, SEO, Printing & Internet marketing company looking to hire a sales team member. We have 10+ years experience in the Web design & marketing field. Work your own hours, competitive commission rates, we can also train the right candidates for sales. Our office is located in New Jersey.<br>
</section>
```

So the examples here don't seem to work.

Comment: Have a [look & a smile](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
preg_match("/(?s)<section id=\"postingbody\">((?:.)*?)<\/section>/i", $compiled_results, $matches2);
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/N4vwoyCqwNHI3MT9)

**Edit:** For example, the following code works as expected for me (the value is in `$matches2`):

```
$compiled_results = '<section id="postingbody">
    Looking to find a side job ( working your own hours ) or career in the new media field & internet marketing? Web design, graphic design, SEO, Printing & Internet marketing company looking to hire a sales team member. We have 10+ years experience in the Web design & marketing field. Work your own hours, competitive commission rates, we can also train the right candidates for sales. Our office is located in New Jersey.<br>
</section>';
preg_match("/(?s)<section id=\"postingbody\">((?:.)*?)<\/section>/i", $compiled_results, $matches2);
var_dump($matches2);
```

Comment: Please see my edit; it works fine for me, given the examples you gave above.

Comment: Sorry Ed - indeed it does work. That's what I get for working on code and being tired! True gentleman and a scholar! Thank you so much.

Comment: Always glad to help someone out! Get some rest. :)

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not always suited for this type of HTML/XML parsing. Better to use DOM parser in PHP.

However if you really have to then this regex should work for you with `/s` flag (DOTALL):

```
preg_match('# id="postingbody">.*?</section>#is', $compiled_results, $matches2);
```